# Counting the number of occurrences for unique comma separated values in Google Sheets

Tags: parsing, google-sheets

I've been working on this [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1b0hhmZynOTt9IiRyCWX2oTWOFQTeMBt6NAq2BDrL26M/edit#gid=1956640564).

Using Sheet2, I'm trying to count how many times a comma separated value occurs on sheet1 using the following query.

```
=query( transpose(split(JOIN(",",Sheet1!A1:A),",",true,true)), "SELECT Col1,count(Col1) group by Col1")
```

I cannot explain why certain values are identified more than once such as Asynchronous writing / speculative reading.

Comment: rows #2 and #21 contains the same wording except a blank

Answer (score 2):

use:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(FLATTEN(TRIM(SPLIT(QUERY(
 FILTER(Sheet1!A2:A&",", Sheet1!A2:A<>""),,9^9), ","))), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) group by Col1 label count(Col1)''"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Apply trim

```
=query( transpose(arrayformula(trim(split(JOIN(",",Sheet1!A1:A),",",true,true)))), "SELECT Col1,count(Col1) group by Col1")
```

[TRIM()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094140)